# Swift protect hard coded string for privacy

Tags: ios, swift

```
let password = "ThisisASecretStringContainingAPassword"
let username = "name@gmail.com"
```

In Swift, what is the best way to hide and protect hard-coded information that needs to be kept private? Anyone have any advice or experience with this in swift?

I have found this but how safe can it be? What are your thoughts?
https://medium.com/theappspace/increase-the-security-of-your-ios-app-by-obfuscating-sensitive-strings-swift-c915896711e6

This is not the same. Im asking the best way for protection of hard coding and using in the app not using web key! Someone answered with leave it at that is the best way. Is that a joke? There has to be more input. Leave mine open. My question is legitimate to help others and myself.

Comment: Search on obfuscation https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+obfuscate+password+

Comment: Of course it is the same. The duplicate is about hiding keys and passwords and other critical, private values.